# How do I change the layout of listLayer Arcgis

Tags: javascript, arcgis

I would like to know if I can change the layerlist's layout, for example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfeJ4.png)

I'm needing to change the opacity and size of popup on the top-right, is it possible?! The component that I'm using is LayerList.

I tried to set the opacity directly on the layer, but it is not possible and I didn't see any other solution on the internet to allow modify the popup's layout.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.